# 'geometryService' argument is missing

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am using 'queryTask.execute' to get features from a layer. And have change the geometry-paths of the features(polyline), trying to save the changes using 'applyEdits'. This is throwing error 'esri.geometry.normalizeCentralMeridian: 'geometryService' argument is missing'. Updating any attribute is working while path edit is not working.

```js
queryTask.execute(query, function(data){
    if(data.features && data.features.length){
            for(let i in data.features){
                connectedBoxIds = data.features[i].attributes.connectedBoxId.split(',');
                pathIndex = Number(connectedBoxIds.indexOf(componentId)) + 1;
                data.features[i].geometry.paths[0][pathIndex] = newVertex;
            }
            var resultLayer = wireLayer.applyEdits(null, data.features, null);
            resultLayer.then(_ => {
                console.log(_);
            }).otherwise(err => console.warn('error', err));

        }
    });
    queryTask.on('error', lang.hitch(this, 'queryTaskErrorHandler'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is asking you to specify a valid geometry service in your application in order to manipulate/correct the polyline prior to saving the edit.

[Geometry services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Geometry_Service/02r3000000qs000000/) ship *out of the box* with ArcGIS Server, but you're also welcome to point at a utility instance associated with ArcGIS Online if you prefer.

```
esriConfig.geometryService = "http://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer";
```

more info: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.config-amd.html

Comment: I am using 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-arcgis-js-app' to set up a dojo argis project. And I am able to edit any feature loaded by default. Hope I must be there in config

Comment: you shouldn't expect it to be exposed via a config.  you'll need to write the code yourself.  i'd suggest placing it in 'src/app/components/map/MapView.js'

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, John. 
But for my issue 'selectFeatures(query, selectionMethod?, callback?, errback?)' is working fine instead of 'queryTask'. This returns graphics as we loop through the graphics of a layer.